# Как присвоить переменную к указателю?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, указатели, инициализация, объявление

У меня проблема с присваиванием значения переменной "a" к указателю "knockback", возникает ошибка: "error-type knockback это объявление не содержит класс хранения или спецификатор типа".

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;

int*knockback;
int a=8000;
knockback = &a;
int nknockback = 12;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще-то все действия в программе на C++ выполняются в функциях, начиная с функции `main`. Вы объявляете переменные в глобальной области видимости, а тут возможна только *инициализация*, но не присваивание, которое вы постарались выполнить строчкой

```
knockback = &a;
```

Если вы напишете

```
int a=8000;
int*knockback = &a;
int nknockback = 12;
```

проблем не будет - объявлены и инициализированы три переменные.

Не будет проблем и при переносе присваивания в `main`:

```
int*knockback;
int a=8000;
int nknockback = 12;

int main()
{
    knockback = &a;
}
```